# MySQL returning an empty result set

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I tried doing this in PHP but I got 0 rows returned all the time. Then after some time searching around on StackOverflow, I saw a tip to try doing it in SQL first to see if the results are returned properly.

I tried to do it in SQL and it's returning an empty result set all the time, even tho the values are there.

SQL

```
SELECT * FROM `serials_table` WHERE `ser_key`='ABCD-EFGH-IJKL-MNOP'
```

PHP

```
$result = $link->query("SELECT * FROM serials_table WHERE ser_key='$key'");
```

Both are returning null value.

ser_key column is set to text type, coallition: utf8_unicode_ci, Null: No, Default: None

The serial key entry is in there and the column 'ser_key' exists as well as the table 'serials_table'. Also I directly copy-pasted the serial key from the table and placed it into the query to avoid any typos.

Did I make some errors with the table structure or something?

I have no idea what to do here, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM serials_table WHERE ser_key like '%ABCD-EFGH-IJKL-MNOP%'` to see if it is a trim issue

Comment: Can you check if there are hidden spaces in the value field of column `ser_key`. 

For example; `'ABCD-EFGH-IJKL-MNOP   '`

Comment: @juergend Yes it is working now. How can I avoid that issue from happening again? Also, could you post this as an answer so I can mark it as solved? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this works

```
SELECT * FROM serials_table WHERE ser_key like '%ABCD-EFGH-IJKL-MNOP%'
```

Then you have leading or trailing spaces in your data.

To revert that update your existing table data like this

```
update serials_table 
set ser_key = trim(ser_key)
```

After that check where you insert or update the `ser_key`. In that code segment check if you put only trimmed data in there.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM `serials_table` WHERE TRIM(`ser_key`)='ABCD-EFGH-IJKL-MNOP'
```

Remove white spaces

```
UPDATE `serials_table` set `ser_key`= TRIM(`ser_key`);
```

Comment: I was about to say to TRIM the input